# Add a new instance variable to a subclass on construction without overriding the parent class's __init__()?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a base class `Parent` defined as:

```py
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
```

And a class `Child` which inherits from it. `Child` has an additional instance variable `e` which has a value by default and so its value is not passed as a parameter to `__init__`. I don't want to override `Parent.__init__` in `Child` with the exact same 4 parameters and then call `super().__init__(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)` as well as `self.e = 5`, but I do want to instantiate `self.e = 5` when a `Child` object is instantiated.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use dataclasses? https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance

Comment: The example I gave is very simplified. The instance variables are specific complex objects and not just "data", and there are additional complex methods, as well as additional logic in the parent's constructor, so I would prefer not to use dataclasses

Comment: would overwriting the __init__ method as __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): ; super.__init__(*args, **kwargs); self.e=5 work for you? I think that is as condensed as you can get

Answer (score 0):

The advice given in https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ would be to use `super` and use keyword-only parameters to define `Parent.__init__` (which is an optional way to force anyone instantiating `Child` to use keyword arguments):

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, *, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.e = 5


c = Child(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
```